# product + price printing cost

Tags: magento2

I need to create products where I can add printing service.

Product price $20 (50sheets)

printing service: full color

50-149 sheets + $0.234/sheet

150-299 sheets + $0.157/sheet

300-599 sheets + $0.136/sheet

600+ sheets +0.119/sheet

Wat is the best way to accomplish this?